# iScroll4: How to hide scrollbar when not interacting

Tags: iscroll, iscroll4

Is it possible to hide the scrollbar when not scrolling, and show it again when start interacting with it?

My code:

```
new iScroll('js-queue',{
    hideScrollbar: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `hidescrollbars` is set to `true` so there is no need to pass it through as a parameter again. Just set `hScrollbar / vScrollbar` to `false` in your iScroll call and that should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this and it is working on my side,

```
myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {checkDOMChanges:true, hScrollbar:false, vScrollbar:true,hideScrollbar: true,scrollbarClass: 'myScrollbar' });
```